# Ember.Controller array content filtering

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kristaps_petersons/9wteJ/2/ it loads 3 objects and shows them in a view. Data is shown alright, but i can not filter it before i show it. 
This

```
nodes: function(){
        this.get('controller.content').filter(function(item, idx, en){
            console.log('should log this atleast 3x')
        })        
        return this.get('controller.content')
    }.property('controller.content')
```

method is called when template iterates over array of values, but it never goes in to the loop and print `console.log('should log this atleast 3x')` why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to replace `controller.content` while also binding to it. You need to define another property, such as `filteredContent` and bind it to `controller.content`. Take a look at how Ember.SortableMixin computes the variable `arrangedContent` for controllers with a `sortProperties` variable defined.  Using that method as a template I would implement it like this:

```
 filteredContent: Ember.computed('content', function() {
     var content = this.get('content');

     return this.filter(function(item, idx, en) {
        console.log('should log this atleast 3x');
     });        
 }).cacheable()
```

This should be implemented in the controller, not the view. The controller is the place for data manipulation, computed properties, and bindings.

Then bind the view layout to `filteredContent` instead of `content` to show the filtered data.  Then both the original content and the filtered content are available.

Comment: I changed the code like you said, but still it does not go into the loop. Check out fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kristaps_petersons/9wteJ/11/
i added two console.log lines  
`console.log('BEFORE should log this atleast 3x')`  
`console.log('AFTER should log this atleast 3x')`  

it prints these lines, just as before, but does not go into the loop  . although all nodes are returned

Comment: I've recently been working on a live filter for an Ember ArrayController. It builds on this example. See http://jsbin.com/UvePomO/4/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it working, but it feels a bit strange. First i moved method to Controller class and changed it to look like this:

```
nodes: function(){
    console.log('BEFORE should log this atleast 3x', this.get('content.length'))
    this.get('content').forEach(function(item, idx, en){
        console.log('should log this atleast 3x')
    })
    console.log('AFTER should log this atleast 3x', this.get('content.length'))
    return this.get('content')
}.property('content').cacheable()
```

as it should be same as buuda's recomedation, because as i understand from docs `.poperty()` is the same as `Ember.computed`. As it was still not working, i changed `.property('content')` to `.property('content.@each')` and it was working. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kristaps_petersons/9wteJ/21/ . I guess, that tempate first creates a binding to `controller.content` and as content itself does not change does not notify this method again, instead template pulls data as it becomes available.